# Synonymize [cell] and [cell-biology]?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I recently discovered [cell](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cell) and after browsing through most of the ~40 tagged questions, I think the [cell-biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cell-biology) tag applies to all the questions and (more importantly) fits better.

What do you think? I suggested a tag synonym, so feel free to [express your opinion by voting on it](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/cell-biology/synonyms).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that they could be synonymized, and have voted. I guess that some might have used the [cell](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cell) tag in a purely descriptive way (Q dealing with cells), but the [cell-biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cell-biology) tag should still apply and be more general.

Answer (score 3):

The synonym reached its score of +4 votes and was created.